# HTTP cache invalidation with API Platform and AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, api-platform.com, http-caching

I am trying to implement a HTTP cache invalidation with API Platform and AWS CloudFront and as I can read in [API Platform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#enabling-the-built-in-http-cache-invalidation-system):

> Support for reverse proxies other than Varnish can easily be added by implementing the `ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\PurgerInterface`

I have coded an implementation but now I can not make the built-in cache invalidation system -should be the event listener `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\EventListener\PurgeHttpCacheListener`- it just keep injecting the `ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\VarnishPurger` instead.

What I did basically, in `config/services.yml` -having autowire enabled:

```
    ApiPlatform\Core\HttpCache\PurgerInterface: '@App\ApiPlatform\HttpCache\CloudFrontPurger'

    ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\EventListener\PurgeHttpCacheListener:
        arguments:
            $purger: '@App\ApiPlatform\HttpCache\CloudFrontPurger'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! Found the issue. `PurgeHttpCacheListener` is using a service ID so it cannot be autowired [according to the Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring).

From `vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine_orm_http_cache_purger.xml`:

```
        <service id="api_platform.doctrine.listener.http_cache.purge" class="ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\EventListener\PurgeHttpCacheListener">
            <argument type="service" id="api_platform.http_cache.purger" />
            <argument type="service" id="api_platform.iri_converter" />
            <argument type="service" id="api_platform.resource_class_resolver" />

            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" />
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="onFlush" />
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="postFlush" />
        </service>
```

The solution is simple. In your `service.yml` just inject it using its service ID as follow:

```
    api_platform.http_cache.purger:
        class: App\ApiPlatform\HttpCache\CloudFrontPurger
```